# Why not check for null like c# when raising custom events in vb.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972975.aspx#usercontrols_topic5) page which talks about raising events. In here for c# syntax, it checks if the event is null and then raises the event. Why is not the same for vb.net?

```
public event CommandEventHandler ProductSelectionChanged;
```

In some method this is called.

```
if (ProductSelectionChanged != null)
{
    ProductSelectionChanged(this, e);
}
```

In vb it's raise event. Why is the difference. Also, this page talks about using this

```
Protected WithEvents products As DisplayProductSelection.
```

I tried it without this and event was handled. Is it a good practice to use this?

Comment: I'm not a VB guy but I believe VB's RaiseEvent does the null check internally for you. Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: With the c# code, it will work when something is subscribed to the event, but you need the null check to ensure something subscribed to the event before you try to raise it.  Without it, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VB.Net `RaiseEvent` statement internally performs the `Nothing` (`null`) check for you.  This is not done in C#, and must be handled manually.  Note that many other languages, such as F# and C++/CLI, also don't require the manual null check.

This is often nicer, with the rare exception being if you want to have special logic which handles the case of the event having no subscribers (ie: and `else` branch), in which case the [VB.Net Team has blogged about one approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/09/25/testing-events-for-nothing-null-doug-rothaus.aspx) to handle that scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. Why do I need to add this? Protected WithEvents products As DisplayProductSelection. Like I said in my question, the event was handled without this piece of code. What is the significance of it and why would I need to use it?

Comment: @SamsonBujju See: http://imar.spaanjaars.com/300/what-do-i-need-protected-withevents-for  You need that if you want to use `Handles`